# How to set Gradle custom ant task classpath?

Tags: java, ant, build, gradle

I have a custom Ant task in my codebase that I need to use from Gradle. There are plenty of examples of how to use a task that is packaged in a jar file, but this is different.

My `taskdef` should look something like:

```
ant.taskdef(
    name: 'generator',
    classname: 'MyGenerator', 
    classpath: ???
)
```

The `classpath` should include everything in `bin/` (where my code gets compiled to) **and** all the jars listed in the `dependencies` section of the build script. How to fill in the blank?

I've tried a few different things, resulting in either obscure messages like `The <taskdef> type doesn't support nested text data` or typical `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is described in the [user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html#N1155E) under 'Using custom Ant tasks in your build'

basically you want to declare a `configuration`, add dependencies to it in the `dependencies` section and then use `asPath` in your `taskdef classpath`

Comment: Right, but what would the `dependencies` be for the case I described?The difference in my case is that I need the `classpath` to be a directory plus all the `compile` dependencies.

Comment: If that is really what you want, use `classpath: sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath`. Make sure to do this in a task action, not at configuration time.

Answer (score 1):

As Perryn Fowler wrote, you should declare a `configuration` and `dependencies` section. Here is an example I found: https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-common-plugins/blob/master/webdav.gradle